# Biblatex-numeric - Remove comma between year and page

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, bibliographystyle

I am very desperate using bibliography styles for my thesis, as there are very strict guidelines for doing so. This is how it should look in the refereneces:
[image]
Since it didn't work with Bibtex, I am now using Biblatex and so far I have:

```
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,sorting=none,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1\isdot}
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
page = {{}{}},
pages = {{}{}},}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers = {et\,al\adddot},}
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{ \space}
```

[image]

Now the only thing missing is to remove the comma between the year and pages. How can I do that?

(I manually adjusted the title to italic and the volume to bold in the bib file. If there was still an overarching command for this would be even better.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: You have a slightly higher chance of getting a good (and tested!) answer quickly, if you share not only a code snippet with us, but a fully compilable example document along with a relevant test `.bib` entry. That way we can all compile the same code and see the exact same thing. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864.